# How to re-arrange the number

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

I have a number which I need to re-arrange to find the largest number. As an example input number is 355 so for this number I need to find the largest number which can be formed by re-arranging the digits. So for 355, various combination can be possible after re-arranging -

```
355, 535 and 553
```

So here 553 is the largest number and that's what I need to return. Basically given an input, I need to find the largest number which can be formed by re-arranging the numbers.

How should I go ahead and solve this problem?

So far I am able to do shuffle the numbers like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //generate random number
    int number = 355;

    //put each digit in an element of a list
    List<Character> numberList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (char c : String.valueOf(number).toCharArray()) {
        numberList.add(c);
    }

    //shuffle
    Collections.shuffle(numberList);

    //output
    String shuffledNumber = "";
    for (Character c : numberList) {
        shuffledNumber += c;
    }
    System.out.println(shuffledNumber);

}
```

But I am confuse how can I find the largest number given an input after rearranging the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to rearrange the numbers so that, if we read it from left to write, it should be largest number among all the arrangements,
then it's simple, you just need to sort the number in descending order.

**Try this code :**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    //generate random number
    int number = 355;

    String numStr = number + "";
    char[] numCharArr = numStr.toCharArray();
    int[] numArr = new int[numStr.length()];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < numCharArr.length ; i ++) {
        numArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(numCharArr[i] + "");
    }


    // Sort in descending order
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numArr.length ; i ++) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < i ; j ++) {

            if(numArr[i] > numArr[j]) {
                // swap
                int temp = numArr[i];
                numArr[i] = numArr[j];
                numArr[j] = temp;
            }

        }
    }

    String largestNumber = "";
    for(int i : numArr) {
        largestNumber += i;
    }

    System.out.println("The largest number is : " + largestNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you actually need to create all the combinations, I wouldn't bother.
You can actually do it using arithmetic, but in this case it's probably easier in terms of strings

naive algorithm:

- source number = number.toString()
- target number = ""
- While source number is not empty

  - d = remove biggest number from source number
  - target number += d

You can then convert target number back to an int if required.

Another approach would be count the number of 9s and append that many 9s to the result. Repeat for 8s, then 7s, then 6s...